# Loading Pytorch model in C# with Binary Reader

Tags: python, c#, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to read and study the basic Model Structures of some of the Pytorch models on HuggingFace.

NOTE: I do not want to convert the model to Onnx, this is not what I want.

I have set the `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` so I can load objects larger than 4Gb.

```
<configuration>  
    <runtime>  
        <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />  
    </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Open and Read the Models is easy:

```
public static void Load(string modelPath)
{

List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();

using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(modelPath))
using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{

// Read in all Bytes.
while (binaryReader.BaseStream.Position != binaryReader.BaseStream.Length)
{
bytes.Add(binaryReader.ReadByte());
}
}
}
```

Some of the Model can be read as a String, some are different types.

My Question is, how do we convert all of the Types necessary, without knowing what's coming next?

```
string JsonString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
```

Is this enough to properly read in the Model? As a Pytorch Graph Representation. Is there a better, faster way to do it?

> "??\0\0\0\0\0\0{"**metadata**":{"format":"pt"},"model.embed_tokens.weight":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[51200,2560],"data_offsets":[0,262144000]},"model.layers.0.input_layernorm.bias":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[2560],"data_offsets":[262144000,262149120]},"model.layers.0.input_layernorm.weight":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[2560],"data_offsets":[262149120,262154240]},"model.layers.0.mlp.fc1.bias":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[10240],"data_offsets":[262154240,262174720]},"model.layers.0.mlp.fc1.weight":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[10240,2560],"data_offsets":[262174720,314603520]},"model.layers.0.mlp.fc2.bias":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[2560],"data_offsets":[314603520,314608640]},"model.layers.0.mlp.fc2.weight":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[2560,10240],"data_offsets":[314608640,367037440]},"model.layers.0.self_attn.dense.bias":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[2560],"data_offsets":[367037440,367042560]},"model.layers.0.self_attn.dense.weight":{"dtype":"F16","shape":[2560,2560],"data_offsets":[367042560,380149760]},"model.layers.0.self_attn.k_proj.bias":{"dtype":..."

Should we expect a Json String format? My early experiments show some of the model seems to be in Json String Format.

Comment: Seems the top portion of the Model is in part Json, ending with ']}}', after that, I cant read the Binary, it seems to be encoded in a non common encoder or possibly even encrypted or Compressed. Wish I was a bit more experienced in Binary Data Formats.

Comment: A binaryReader.ReadSingle(); seems to read these bytes.